# how to fetch my syllables so I can console log them

Tags: javascript, jquery

the JSON looks like this:

```
{
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "TestAfterCodeCleaning",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestAfterCodeCleaning",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "testikels",
      "syllables": [
        "test",
        "ikels",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
 }
}
```

This is how I try to fetch the `syllables` so I can `console.log()` them:

```
var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises.syllables;
```

the problem however: This shows in my `console.log()` undefined. Why and how?

The complete code looks like this:

```
function prepareCheck() {
$.getJSON('json_files/jsonData_' + ID + '.json', function(json) {
  $(document).on('keyup', '.syl-input', function() {
    var syllableval = $(idsyll).val();
     var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises.syllables;
  });
});
}
```

Note: The JSON has one `syllables`, because I thought it would be easier for you to read, however what should be done to fetch all the `syllables` (in case there are more then one array of `syllables`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `exercises[0]` instead of `exercises` because `exercises` is an array of objects in this case only having one item at index `0`.

`var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[0].syllables;`

```js
var json = {
"main_object": {
"id": "new",
"getExerciseTitle": "TestAfterCodeCleaning",
"language": "nl_NL",
"application": "lettergrepen",
"main_object": {
  "title": "TestAfterCodeCleaning",
  "language": "nl_NL",
  "exercises": [
    {
      "word": "testikels",
      "syllables": [
        "test",
        "ikels",
        "",
        ""
      ]
    }
  ]
},
"dataType": "json"
 }
}

var jsyl = json.main_object.main_object.exercises[0].syllables;

console.log(jsyl); // [ 'test', 'ikels', '', '' ]
```

Comment: and what if it contains more then one array of syllables? What should I do then ?(I took this example, because it has less code in it... therefore making it easier for you to read). or doesn't this matter at all?

Comment: you can iterate through the array using loops or array methods.

Comment: could you elaborate on this?

Comment: You mean what if `exercises` contained more than one object having the property `syllables`. Right?

Comment: Did the job! Thank you very much.